# Cryptographic Testing

Tags: cryptography, penetration-test, aes, nist, initialisation-vector

Given an algorithm (say, AES), how to create/generate test vectors?

I have tried using the NIST test vectors for AES and found it to be working fine with a package of "chilkat". Suppose, for a certain algorithm, NIST has not provided test vectors, how do I generate test vectors to test the algorithm?

Comment: Related: [Test vectors for ciphers](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/test-vectors-for-ciphers) at Crypto.SE.

Comment: @StackzOfZtuff , this is a slightly different one. Thanks a lot.